# How to force https in IIS on windows server without any "/" problem?

Tags: redirect, iis, https, iis-10

I am running iis on windows server and i have a valid ssl installed.
i forced https exactly as said [here](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/)

It redirects http://example.com to https://example.com/
but it also adds another problem
by redirecting http://example.com/example/ to http://example.com//example/  (another "/" comes extra)
it does not give any error but i dont like it happen , i have never faced such thing while I was in apache but it happens in iis. i just want to change http to https but not "/".

THIS IS HOW I CONFIGURED https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "/" at the end of the url, you can use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```